# How to stop Tomcat logging?

Tags: tomcat, logging

Tomcat automatically does its logging, and the logging files are all under `/logs` directory. As far as I know, the logging property is `/conf/logging.properties`. How can I stop all the logging?

Comment: Maybe a better title for this question would be "How can I create a maintenance nightmare?" or "How to make sure no one never noticed problems?" :-)

Comment: @AaronDigulla, not if your `tomcat` is behind a reverse-proxy that already produces its own access-log; why duplicate?

Answer (score 5):

To stop access log (default tomcat setting) go to:

```
conf/server.xml
```

and remove the following config:

```
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

to disable common log, go to:

```
conf/logging.properties
```

and comment the following line

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't start Tomcat. No Tomcat, no logging.

On a more serious note, don't. Just don't. This sounds like a surefire recipe to cause problems when you're gone, not available or don't remember anymore what you did.

Instead, install a log rotator which deletes old log files after N days.

Also make sure that Tomcat doesn't write too much into `catalina.out` since you can't rotate that.

For this, I patch the start script and pipe through `head -10000`. Replace this

```
>> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"
```

with

```
2>&1 | head -10000 >> "$CATALINA_OUT" &
```

If there is an error starting Tomcat, I'll still see it. But no more than 10'000 lines of log will be written to that file, so it won't grow forever.

Note: Simply deleting `catalina.out` will not work. On Windows, it will fail since it's still open. On Unix, only the directory entry will be deleted (making the file inaccessible for anyone except processed which have it open). The file will still take up space on the hard disk and it will continue to grow.

Related articles:

- [logrotate doesn't rotate catalina.out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729722/logrotate-doesnt-rotate-catalina-out)

Comment: http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-to-stop-logging-to-catalina-out-with-tomcat-6-0. I used this method to disable writing logs to `catalina.out`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Will it work if I comment out the `handlers` line and `.handlers` line in the `logging.properties` file?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your `logging.properties`. Is Tomcat running on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Oh, and which version of Tomcat?

Comment: If you're running tomcat in a proper systemd unit with non-forking process, your logs will be handled automatically if put to stdout, so there is no need for a loggin configuration.

Comment: how to prevent tomcat from writing too much into catalina.out? links are broken

Comment: There might be legit cases to disable logging. For example if it's handled by a logging framework in the code.

Comment: @Imaskar The problem with Tomcat is that it logs important errors which make it impossible to start your app BEFORE your app's log framework is even loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to stop logging but to limit it to fixed amount via these steps.

1. In `.../apache-tomcat.../conf/logging.properties` set `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = WARNING`.
2. In `.../apache-tomcat.../bin/catalina.sh` replace each mention of

`>> "$CATALINA_OUT" 2>&1 "&"`

to

`2>&1 | tail -1000000 > "$CATALINA_OUT" &`

or to this, if you want additionally set filter to write only `WARNING` messages:

`2>&1 | grep WARNING | tail -1000000 > "$CATALINA_OUT" &`

Thus `catalina.out` will always contain only last 1000000 lines of logs.