catalina.out is very large and failed to rotate
catalina.out is very large and failed to rotate
I have set my /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat like this:
/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina*.* {
copytruncate
daily
rotate 90
compress
missingok
size 10M
}

But catalina.out still not rotated and keep growing to 5GB.
I tried manual run /usr/sbin/logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf, at line of catalina.out rotating shown as below:
considering log /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
  log needs rotating
rotating log /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out, log->rotateCount is 90
dateext suffix '-20240720'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed
copying /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out to /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out-20240720
truncating /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
compressing log with: /bin/gzip

How can I fixed this?
I tried setup /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat, and manual run /usr/sbin/logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf
I need logrotate to rotate my catalina.out

Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729722/logrotate-doesnt-rotate-catalina-out?rq=2
